# How to run Composer on Homestead?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homestead

Where is Composer installed within Laravel Homestead virtual machine – the main question is that why it isn't aliased as 'composer'?

When Homestead is provisioning I can see it running composer self-update so it is there...

Update: Found this in homestead.rb

```
# Update Composer On Every Provision
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "/usr/local/bin/composer self-update"
end
```

In ~/.homestead/aliases was this (I don't recall for sure if it was added by me):

```
alias composer='composer.phar'
```

If that alias was there as default, it doesn't point to global composer installation. So anyway, there is no global alias defined for composer even it is installed globally in Homestead?

Comment: I'd guess because most people run it locally rather than on the VM.

Comment: I cannot run composer from OSX terminal – not at least when MAMP is installed – as I haven't got around of "needs MCrypt installed" problem...

Comment: `composer` is available for me in a Homestead box.

Comment: @envision You should strongly consider getting [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). It'd be a simple `brew install php56 php56-mcrypt` (or any other version of PHP you want) there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer has been installed in Homestead machine at path */usr/local/bin/composer*.

However, there has been no aliases created, possibly because different people are used to different shorthands.

Comment: Also, this makes global call via `composer` possible.